# mysql database for Japanese/English input: utf8_unicode_ci or utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a mysql database that contains Japanese and English strings.

current collation: ***utf8_general_ci.***

I must do queries for Japanese words in a string using LIKE %'japaneseWordHere'%. Currently it works almost ok with utf8_general_ci but sometimes it will skip a record because, i assume, the previous/proceeding character is not stored correctly in utf8_general_ci.

I have found that utf8_general_ci is a little old and buggy and learned about:

1. utf8_unicode_ci
2. utf8mb4_unicode_ci

I was doing some reading and could not specifically find a good answer to this.

If anyone works with Japanese myslq databases or someone who knows what is best, any responses would be welcome.

Should I change from utf8_general_ci to ***utf8_unicode_ci*** or ***utf8mb4_unicode_ci*** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci**

> UTF-8 is an encoding for the Unicode character set, which supports
>   pretty much every language in the world.
>
> The only difference comes with sorting your results, different letters
>   might come in a different order in other languages. Also, comparing **a**
>   to **ä** might behave differently in another collation.

**2. Between utf8mb4_unicode_ci and utf8_unicode_ci**

> For a BMP character, utf8 and utf8mb4 have identical storage
>   characteristics: same code values, same encoding, same length
>
> For a supplementary character, utf8 cannot store the character at all,
>   while utf8mb4 requires four bytes to store it. Since utf8 cannot store
>   the character at all, you do not have any supplementary characters in
>   utf8 columns and you need not worry about converting characters or
>   losing data when upgrading utf8 data from older versions of MySQL.